# Creating a graphical editor for a domain specific UI application using Eclipse modeling technologies

Tags: eclipse

I want to creating a graphical editor which a physician can use to create user interfaces  to define state-based interactive dialogue based diagnosis systems for simple diseases. Each screen consists of simple UI elements like a textarea,button and these are in a container to make up the state. Once he defines many screens with text and buttons or photos/videos, he wants to save the configuration in a XML file. How can I use the Eclipse modeling technologies to create a graphical editor to do this task

Example below: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the GMF tutorial is a good place to start: http://wiki.eclipse.org/GMF_Tutorial